# Closing event triggered on both UserClosing and this.close

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form on which there is a LogOutEvent and a form closing event.
Here is the code,

```
private void btnLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       DialogResult yesNo = MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you want to Log Off?", "Log Off", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

        if (yesNo == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            new LoginForm();
            this.Close();
            string tst2 = Logout(AgentId, AgentPwd, ExtensionId);
            if (tst2 == "TCF000")
                MessageBox.Show(" Logout Success");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Logout Failed");
        }
}
```

And a Form Closing Event

```
private void MainGUI_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            DialogResult yesNo = MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you want to Log Off?", "Log Off", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

            if (yesNo == DialogResult.Yes)
            { 
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
         }
}
```

My Problem is when i click on the LogOut button its calling the form closing event. Can anybody advice a better code for this?

When i click on close 'X' it should close the application and when i click on LogOut it should close the current window and go to the login form.

Comment: you are calling this.Close() so that would trigger close event

Comment: @V4Vendetta @Kragen @Marc But I thought that the CloseReason.UserClose would only be trigger when X is clicked. I was wrong. Tell me what are the triggering events for form closing and when they wil be triggered

Comment: This might [Help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631490/bug-in-formclosingeventargs-closereason)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure that there is a better solution, but this does work:

```
private bool loggingOut;

private void Form1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.loggingOut = true;
    this.Close();
    // This is optional as we are closing the form anyway
    this.loggingOut = false;
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing && !loggingOut)
    {
        // Handle form closing here
    }
}
```

This allows your form closing event handler to identify if another method is invoking the form close, and skip the normal handling if it is.

Alternatively you could just `Hide` the form instead, and re-use the same form instance the next time the user logs in.

Answer (score 2):

well... yes! the form is closing; why *wouldn't* it fire the event?

If the `CloseReason` isn't helping, then just throw a `bool` field onto the form that you set to true when you click logout; and check that field in the closing event.