# Hide Process from Task Manager

Tags: .net, vb.net, process, taskmanager

I'm doing a GameGuard for a game, but do not want people to be able to close it. I would like to make it disappear from the task manager.

I tried using:

```
Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
```

But it did not work. Since then, I have done much research on the internet and nothing shows an example or says something about how to do this.

People think it is hacker-like to hide processes, but in my case, I'm doing this for a game GameGuard.

I want it to be gone completely from the task manager.

Comment: Task*BAR* or Task*MANAGER*???

Comment: Crono, TaskMANAGER Process.

Comment: You can hide it from the "task" tab, not the processes one... at least from .net on Vista+ with 64-bits you can't.
With windows xp you might find some old code with poorly perfomance that might accomplish that, and perhaps if you want to try it in windows 7+ you could search harder for it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you can't hide a process from the Task Manager, **and that's a good thing**. Preventing a user from seeing and ending an active process is plain and simply wrong. Can you imagine being an administrator and yet not being able to end a process on your machine? :)

As for the `ShowInTaskBar` property, it only determines if the form is visible as a Taskbar button or not. Not related to Task Manager in any way.

**ANSWER TO YOUR COMMENT BELOW:**

If you are using Winforms then in your form's [`Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event there's a `CloseReason` property that can inform you about the app being closed from the Task Manager. Unfortunately, you will find out that [it ain't 100% reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631490/bug-in-formclosingeventargs-closereason).

Comment: Would it be possible to close by the tasks the program manager, it run a command before closing?

Comment: What you likely want is for your program to require the GameGuard to be running for it to run. Perhaps your game and the GameGuard can talk to eachother in some sort of heart beat pattern.

Comment: Crono, 
`
     If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
            Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("CabalMain")
            For Each p As Process In pProcess
                p.Kill()
            Next
            End
        End If
`

Comment: @LeonardoJoksan I'm not sure what you are asking me here. If you have a new question you should start a new topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is an overly asked question in here by a lot of people and the solution varies in terms of complexity of implementation to the necessity of such requirement. Here are your possible solutions:

- DLL Injection + DLL Hooking in Task Manager and hook APIs that deals with Enumeration of Process. There are a lot of questions and answers around here regarding these topics so before posting another new question go read it first.
- DKOM (Direct Kernel Object Manipulation) which requires you to write a legacy WDM driver and alter the `EPROCESS` of such process in question. I have exentensively explained it over here [IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL to hide a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713467/irp-mj-device-control-to-hide-a-process/32293511#32293511)
- Use SSDT which doesn't work outside the box on x64 and is not generic enough to remain working after updates as indexes changes from version to version and from one service pack to another. So I personally do not recommend the last one.